# Prepositions used after нельзя

Tags: грамматика

I encountered an example on Rosetta Stone which contrasted these three  sentences:

1. Здесь нельзя с собакой
2. Здесь нельзя на машине
3. Здесь нельзя в туфлях

My question is, is there any grammatical reason why to use any of these pronouns and not the others? Are these specific to the noun just as `в школе` and `на почте` have pronouns specific to that noun? Or would `нельзя в собаке` also be just fine?

Comment: `any of these pronouns` - Do you mean prepositions? `нельзя в собаке`- "do smth. while being inside a dog is prohibited" - does it denote something meaningful for you?

Comment: Yes, prepositions, derp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> which contrasted these three sentences

All these sentences have some verb omitted. As we assume these verbs to be different, we naturally have to put different prepositions after them.

> [гулять] **с** собакой --> [walk] **with** a dog
>   [ездить] **на** машине --> [drive] a car (no prepostion needed in English)
>   [ходить] **в** туфлях --> [walk] **in** shoes
>   [???] **в** собаке --> [what???] **inside** a dog

.

> Are these specific to the noun

Specific to both a noun and a verb. I.e. just as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Russian language often drops/omits the verb "to be."  In all of the provided examples the verb **"to be" (быть)** is dropped.

> Здесь нельзя [быть] с собакой
>
> Здесь нельзя [быть] на машине
>
> Здесь нельзя [быть] в туфлях

The choice of a preposition is dictated by how **to be** is connected with the object.

> to be **with** a dog - быть **с** собакой
>
> to be **in** a car - быть **на** машине
>
> to be **in** shoes - быть **в** туфлях